# How do I map 2 services that are marshalled and unmarshalled differently using one single routebuilder?

Tags: java, xml, design-patterns, jaxb, apache-camel

I have 2 services( For now, lets assume service A and B). Service A uses legacy code and is marshalled and unmarshalled differently in the processor. Service B uses the latest code(JaxB Binding) and is marshalled differently. Currently, I have written a Routebuilder that maps to the appropriate service based on the header(using choice operation: if header=X, map to processor A). However, Service A still uses old processors to perform the marshalling and unmarshalling. Is there a way to tell camel to route to a particular service based on how the service is marshalled or unmarshalled. If you need more clarifications, please let me know.

Thanks,
Gautham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first question that comes to mind is, why would you want to route based on implementation specific details? If you change your marshalling you need to change your routing logic as well. It would be easier to split the mapping into seperate routes so service A exist in route A and service B in route B. Then you simply route to route A or route B based on header or some other information. That way, if you change the marshalling in the future or anything else you don't need to change your routing logic.